# Where is there a key to microchip mplab source editor syntax color highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, microchip, mplab

I must be missing something obvious, but, in spite of a lot of internet searching, I cannot find a key to the colours used for syntax highlighting in Microchip MPLAB source code editor. I am sure that interpreting these will help me discover an obscure error in code I copied from an on-line tutorial.

Can anyone please tell me how to find a key to these colours?

OT, I'm in UK, *must* I use American spelling, e.g. color for colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MPLAB v8 press *Edit* | *Properties* and on the *Text* tab select *Choose Colors* to view your syntax highlighting settings.

On MPLAB X press *Tools* | *Options*, select *Fonts & Colors*. Browse through your colour setup on the *Highlighting* tab.

Comment: Thank you for that @mizo. I did find this when I was searching for the key to the colours, but in my version, MPLAB X IDE v1.41, running on Linux, it omits at least two. "#include" is in green, and the file referenced is in orange both with a white background. These may come under the "inherited" foreground colour specified, but my attempts to explore this further were just frustrating: the "Help" button leads to instructions on how to change it, not to what the definitions are,